# How to extend or include auto_complete widget in JS Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

I have some customization in search field in Odoo 10..

I did changes in  svnodoo10\addons\web\static\src\js\widgets\auto_complete.js

Original Code:

```
odoo.define('web.AutoComplete', function (require) {
 "use strict";
  var Widget = require('web.Widget');
  return Widget.extend({
 template: "SearchView.autocomplete",
 render_search_results: function (results) {
    var self = this; 
    var $list = this.$el;
    $list.empty();
    results.forEach(function (result) {
      var $item = self.make_list_item(result).appendTo($list);
     result.$el = $item;
   });
   this.show();
  // My customization
  if(this.history)
  {
         var $first_list = self.$('li:first-child');
   }
   //End
},
});
```

**Extended auto_complete_history.js**

```
odoo.define('product.auto_complete_history', function (require) {
"use strict";  
var AutoComplete = require('SearchView.autocomplete');
return AutoComplete.extend({
  template: "SearchView.autocomplete",
 render_search_results: function (results) {
           this._super();
         if(this.history)
     { 

      var $first_list = self.$('li:first-child');

     }
},});
});
```

But extended file doesn't override the code.
i have tried with Extend , include but no luck

Please anyone help to us how to extend this file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to require the widget. From your code you're requiring the template used by the widget though.

So instead of

```
var AutoComplete = require('SearchView.autocomplete');
```

try

```
var AutoComplete = require('web.AutoComplete');
```

Also, you probably need to use `.include` instead of `.extend` e.g.

```
AutoComplete.include({
    // your changes here ...
});
```